# Submitted Oracle job using dbms_job.submit and it failed but I don't know where to look for an error message

Tags: oracle

We are initiating the rebuilding of many materialized views by using dbms_job.submit to execute a stored procedure that perform the rebuilding. However, I am having trouble trying to figure out how to determine if a submitted job failed. The  issue that I am having is that the job is failing but I cannot identify what the issue is. So, I am trying to start out with a simple example, which is probably failing on a permission issue but I don't know where to look for the error message.

I have the following test procedure that I want to initiate using dbms_job.submit.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYLANID.JUNKPROC 
AS
    lv_msg                 varchar2(3000);
BEGIN

       INSERT INTO MYLANID.junk_log ( msg ) VALUES ('Hello World' );
       commit;
    
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                lv_msg := SUBSTR(sqlerrm, 1, 3000);
                INSERT INTO MYLANID.junk_log ( msg ) VALUES (lv_msg);

END;
/
```

Note that this table is used above:

```
CREATE TABLE MYLANID.JUNK_LOG (
  EVENT_TIME TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT systimestamp,
  MSG VARCHAR2(3000 BYTE))
```

To submit the above procedure as a job, I execute the following anonymous block.

```
declare l_jobid binary_integer;
BEGIN
    dbms_job.submit(job => l_jobid, what => 'BEGIN MYLANID.JUNKPROC; END;'); 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('l_jobid:' || l_jobid);
    commit;
END;
```

I then execute the following SQL...

```
select * from all_jobs;
```

...to see one record that represents my submitted job. When I re-query the all_jobs view, I see that this record quickly disappears from the view within a few seconds, presumably when the job completes. All is happy so far. I would like to use the presence of a record in the all_jobs view to determine whether a submitted job is running or has failed. I expect to be able to tell if it failed by looking at the ALL_JOBS.FAILURES column having a non null value > 0.

The problem, probably a permission issue, begins when I switch to another schema and I switch all of the occurrences of the above SQL and replace "MYSCHEMA" with "ANOTHERSCHEMA" that I also have access to. For example, I create the following

```
Table: ANOTHERSCHEMA.JUNK_LOG 
Procedure: ANOTHERSCHEMA.JUNKPROC
```

I am even able to execute the stored procedure successfully in a query window while logged in as MYSCHEMA:

```
EXEC ANOTHERSCHEMA.JUNKPROC
```

However, if I execute the following code to submit a job that involves running the same ANOTHERSCHEMA procedure but by submitting it as a JOB...

```
declare l_jobid binary_integer;
BEGIN
    dbms_job.submit(job => l_jobid, what => 'BEGIN ANOTHERSCHEMA.JUNKPROC; END;'); 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('l_jobid:' || l_jobid);
    commit;
END;
```

...then, when I query the jobs ALL_JOBS view...

```
select * from all_jobs;
```

...I see that the job has a positive value for the column FAILURE and I have no record of what the error was. This FAILURE count value continues to gradually increment over time as Oracle presumably retries up to 16? times until the job is marked BROKEN in the ALL_JOBS view.

But this is just a simple example and I don't know where to look for the error message that would tell me why the job using ANOTEHRSCHEMA references failed.

**Where Do I look for the error log of failed jobs? I'm wondering if this will be somewhere only the DBA can see...**

**Update:**

The above is just a simple test example. In my actual real world situation, my log shows that the job was submitted but I never see anything in USER_JOBS or even DBA_JOBS, which should show everything. I don't understand why the dbms_job.submit procedure would return the job number of the submitted job indicating that it was submitted but no job is visible in the DBA_JOBS view! The job that I did submit should have taken a long time to run, so I don't expect that it completed faster than I could notice.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: dont' use dbms_job.  Instead, use dbms_scheduler.  It is newer and much richer in what it can do, especially logging.  I leave it as an exercise for the student to look up dbms_scheduler in the version-appropriate _PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference_    And why would you expect DBA_VIEWS or ALL_VIEWS to show anything at all about job execution?

Comment: @pmdba Oracle Version 13.3

Comment: @Ed Thanks for the reply. Funny, I often use the same "that's a homework assignment for you" form of speech as you, so I can appreciate that. As for the 2 views, I misspoke and updated the post to say USER_JOBS and DBA_JOBS.

Comment: @Chad, I asked about the version because with 19c and onward, DBMS_JOB actually calls DBMS_SCHEDULER behind the scenes. Not sure what you mean by version 13.3, though. Should be 12, 18, 19, or 20.

Comment: If you're using `dbms_job` and your Oracle version is before 19c, the error will be written to the database alert log.  That's generally a pain to access if you're not the DBA.  If you were using `dbms_scheduler`, which you probably should, the errors would be written to the data dictionary (`dba_scheduler_job_run_details`) where they are much easier to find.

Comment: @pmdba, sorry, is is Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you probably shouldn't be using `dbms_job`.  That package has been superseded for some time by the `dbms_scheduler` package which is significantly more powerful and flexible.  If you are using Oracle 19c or later, Oracle automatically migrates `dbms_job` jobs to `dbms_scheduler`.

If you are using an Oracle version prior to 19c and a `dbms_job` job fails, the error information is written to the database alert log.  That tends to be a bit of a pain to query from SQL particularly if you're not a DBA.  You can define an external table that reads the alert log to make it queryable.  Assuming you're on 11g, there is a view, `x$dbgalertext`, that presents the alert log information in a way that you can query it but DBAs generally aren't going to rush to give users permission on `x$` tables.

If you use `dbms_scheduler` instead (or if you are on 19c or later and your `dbms_job` jobs get converted to `dbms_scheduler` jobs), errors are written to `dba_scheduler_job_run_details`.  `dbms_scheduler` in general gives you a lot more logging information than `dbms_job` does so you can see things like the history of successful runs without needing to add a bunch of instrumentation code to your procedures.